How add a fee with Stripe in a Blazor implementation
I'm creating a platform with Blazor. The web application is a multitenant application for booking appointments. There are 2 different kind of appointment:

one off: the user pays only for one session
recurring until cancel: the user can book a session a week and every month the platform has to take a payment

For each payment, a small percentage of the amount has to be paid as fee to my Stripe account and the other part sends to the professional.
I saw those links:

GitHub
How to accept Stripe payments via Blazor in .NET 8

Also, I saw the Stripe documentation to transfer amount. There are 2 options for that: collect fees with either an application_fee_amount or transfer_data[amount]. Here there is an example:
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_ESDdbUTrLo4e9SC7uoQqlhd2";

var options = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateOptions
{
    LineItems = new List<Stripe.Checkout.SessionLineItemOptions>
    {
        new Stripe.Checkout.SessionLineItemOptions
        {
            PriceData = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionLineItemPriceDataOptions
            {
                Currency = "usd",
                ProductData = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionLineItemPriceDataProductDataOptions
                {
                    Name = "T-shirt",
                },
                UnitAmount = 1000,
            },
            Quantity = 1,
        },
    },
    PaymentIntentData = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionPaymentIntentDataOptions
    {
        ApplicationFeeAmount = 123,
        TransferData = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionPaymentIntentDataTransferDataOptions
        {
            Destination = "{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}",
        },
    },
    Mode = "payment",
    SuccessUrl = "https://example.com/success",
};
var service = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionService();
service. Create(options);

If I understood correctly, the {{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}} is the Stripe account of my platform and the StripeConfiguration.ApiKey is the client ApiKey?

First thing:
You should be using the Stripe Connect product in order to setup a checkout session with TransferData specified.
connected account Id:
According to the official docs CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID is:

The account (if any) that the payment is attributed to for tax reporting, and where funds from the payment are transferred to after payment success.

I highly recommend reading these articles, as they perfectly match your use case:

Separate Charges and transfers
Create a Charge


api key:
This api key, has nothing to do directly with your checkout session. Commonly you configure it once for your whole application. I prefer to place it in app startup configuration code rather than the service that's meant for setting up a checkout session.

The StripeConfiguration.ApiKey is the secret_key of the platform and the {{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}} is the acct_xxx of the connected account (the merchant on your platform).
